# Get error when try install ImageMagick on FreeBSD

Tags: imagemagick, installation, freebsd, ports

if shortly I got error when tried install ImageMagic from ports on FreeBSD. Any solutions how to fix it?

```
%make install clean
===>  ImageMagick-nox11-6.5.8.10_1 is marked as broken: hdri support broken, disable in options.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/ImageMagick.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, run `make config` and deselect `HDRI` option.